# Clap sound detection in C#

Tags: c#, audio, sound-recognition

I would like to be able to detect a clapping sound. Being pretty new to any form of sound recognition, is there simple any way to do this? If not, any good resources for C# sound recognition/detection?

My goal is to automate a clients media center with some basic clap-based controls.

Comment: This seems like an algorithm problem, not a language problem. I suggest you broaden your query and google searches to other languages and *then* see if/how you want to implement that in C#.

Comment: Thanks, I do agree. I was just leaving it open for any existing libraries/components/frameworks/whatever specific to C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a similar question asked in the past:

[Given an audio stream, find when a door slams (sound pressure level calculation?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499795/given-an-audio-stream-find-when-a-door-slams-sound-pressure-level-calculation)

Although the question was not specific to C#, it does have some ideas for algorithms to use. (Disclosure: Yes, I did answer that question.)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt focus on the language as such, but on the algorithm.

What characteristics of a sound allow you to identify it as a clap? Duration? Intensity? Variation of intensity over time?

Once you've got an algorithm, *then* decide the best way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this will be of any help, but still: [MERL - Sound Recognition](http://www.merl.com/projects/SoundRecognition/). Or better yet, [Clap detection, with microphone](http://lego.daller.dk/?p=19).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem you can solve using a so called Principal Component Analysis. Try to google it. Also other solutions for the famous Cocktail Party Problem may help. But I am sure there are already some libraries out there.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Audio Zone Trigger](http://www.zonetrigger.com/sound-detection/) for $25 it looks like it will do exactly what you want.