# C#.NET Determine blow sound using microphone

Tags: c#, uwp, soundpool

I am working on a UWP app which needs to keep listening to the sound and recognize a hammering sound.
For every blow of hammer strike I need to save the system time.

I have looked at few algorithms like
[Clap sound detection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980673/clap-sound-detection-in-c-sharp)

but none-of-them are close to what I am looking for.

**Here is the flow:**

1. on my **UWP** I click on a button "**Listen Audio**"
2. That will start **hearing** to the sound
3. When there is **sudden spike** in sound wave, which is like a big hammer strike, my code should **trigger an event**
4. That event will capture information related to the hammer striking (mostly timestamp)

Any suggestions for coming up with a good algorithm is appreciated.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow, can I ask you what you already tried doing? I also recommend reading this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on creating Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples

Comment: This goes partially into AI development. I am actually unsure how they pull that off on a Smartphones hardware. Maybe they are fudging it, by applying the sampling Theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem Practically the "hammering" is just a low frequency signal. And if you pick the sampling rate so low you can barely still sample it, you got all the data you need to figure out the Blows/minute.

Comment: Thanks Christopher

Comment: Please see this url (https://piledrivingapp.com/screenshots) also.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140609/942855) gives you what you need.

Link to product Info Page http://www.zonetrigger.com/sound-detection/

Demo link: http://www.zonetrigger.com/sound-detection/azt-demo.html

**Audio Zone Trigger** — $24.95
Audio Zone Trigger is very easy to use: you put triggers on the sound wave, and when the waves go beyond the thresholds, they perform the actions that you have selected. The software was designed with the following purposes in mind: Security, Computer Remote Control and Monitoring. However, because the software can perform any action that you want, you are free to use it in any creative way you can think!

If you don't want to user 3rd party tools and develop your own solution, then you can try this approach [numerical integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500071/942855)