# Is there a library for ball hitting sound detection

Tags: audio, detection

I'm looking for a library to detect when ball hit in a audio of a tennis match.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499795/given-an-audio-stream-find-when-a-door-slams-sound-pressure-level-calculation) topic but I think there is a suite library for this job.
please guide me
tanx

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is a library for this specific task. You can probably implement something from scratch though, using a sliding FFT to generate a power spectrum and some kind of simple template matching in the frequency domain.

Comment: @Ali: which library ? There are plenty of FFT libraries out there, if that's what you mean, e.g. FFTW: http://fftw.org or Kiss FFT: http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft