# Sound Pattern Recognition in Objective C / C (Mac)

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio

Is there any C or Objective-C library that I can use to detect sound patterns on the Mac (e.g. clap of hands)?

Comment: Some relevant info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499795/given-an-audio-stream-find-when-a-door-slams-sound-pressure-level-calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you use `CoreAudio`, it has a few libraries hidden inside that do some pattern recognition.

But in any case, if you have no previous samples to go by, I would recommend something where you sample a clap, and then compare the questionable samples with your samples, allowing some deviation in both the x and y, and then add any successful detections to your sample list and decrease the allowable deviation.

This is a very slow method, but, in my experience, one of the most reliable for recognizing any sound, especially with a large number of starting samples.