# What is a better way in iOS to detect sound level?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, avaudiorecorder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting a clap in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173605/detecting-a-clap-in-ios)

I've googled this problem a lot, and the thing people come up with is "use AVAudioRecorder". The problem with this class, however, is that the metering is bad, i.e. the maximum update frequency is about 0.9 seconds, it detects peaks but not when these peaks end.
I'm trying to find a way to detect audio clicks (e.g. hand clap/snap). Is there a better way than AVAudioRecorder?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html