# Non speech recognition ( Whistle, etc.. )

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I want to build an app that recognizes sounds like whistle and other non speech sounds.

So when someone whistles, method is called or something happens.

Is there any API for that?

I searched a lot but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following guides:

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/ (a bit old, but should do the trick)

[Detecting a clap in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173605/detecting-a-clap-in-ios)

Essentially you can use the [AVAudioRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) class that does the job for you.