# How to detect claps in iOS?

Tags: ios, signal-processing, fft, audio-fingerprinting

I am working on making an app that performs an action when the sound of a clap is recognized. I have looked into simply measuring the average and peak power from an AVAudioRecorder and this works okay, but if there are other sounds then it reports lots of false positives. I believe I need some kind of audio fingerprinting for this to work while other audio is playing. Now I know that this has been asked a lot before on SO, but most of the answers say something along the lines of "Use FFT" and then the person says "Oh okay!" but no clear explanation is given and I still have no idea how to correctly identify sounds using an FFT.

Can anyone clearly explain, cite another tutorial, or post a link to a library that can identify sounds using audio fingerprinting?

Thanks!

Comment: Use FFT.  A clap should have a fairly distinctive frequency spectrum, when you analyze it.  There are some shareware tools available that will let you capture the sound and display the spectrum, but I'm not remembering what they are and I have them on a different box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting a clap in IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173605/detecting-a-clap-in-ios)

Comment: I did some work on clap detection.  See the paper at http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/pubs/icassp05-claps.pdf and the talk slides at http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/talks/claps-2005-03.pdf .  I have the matlab code, but it's a mess.